# Flood Fill Algorithm - number of Empty Area

Tags: algorithm, flood-fill

So I have been trying to implement the Flood Fill Algorithm using 2D Array. I have had success in filling the Array but I am wondering if there is any way to calculate the number of areas that are left unpainted. Just need an idea on how to do this, not asking for any code snippet.

Input :

[image: Input]

Output :

[image: Output]

Comment: You mean, how many separate areas are there after the floodfill (4 on your picture)? If so, then for each non-painted pixel do the floodfill again, and count the amount of calls.

Comment: Not sure if an inversed result is acceptable too. Are the shapes hollow?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Yes, 4 seperate area. I did that but it gives me the no of points that are unpainted (Since I am calling the FloodFill on each pixel). I need to know the no of enclosed area (4 in my case)

Comment: Also, please try to include a better screenshot. In your example, the upper-right shape is not closed so if the flood came from all sides, it should be filled too. The down-left shape also is cropped a bit in the result.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer, yes they are hollow and sorry for the screens.

Comment: Sorry, my questions didn't make any sense given your questions.

Comment: So, you want to count the dots or the amount of dot groups?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer, dot groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i = 0

1. Pick random unfilled dot, increase i by 1
2. Flood-fill from there, but in a different color
3. Repeat until no dots left

i is the amount of groups.

You might want to first create some set of unfilled dots and remove dots in step 1 and 2 to avoid linear scanning through the 2d-array to look for new unfilled dots.

Comment: Thanks, Will try and get back to u :)

Comment: You could probably use one color for everything if you only need the amount of groups. The resulting image would be unusuable then.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:-

1. Start from unfilled point and do floodfill from that point.
2. Count all points filled till floodfill ends
3. the count is u r area for enclosed figure.

Comment: Okay but Can u please tell me how to count the no of Areas ? I am able to get the area by counting calls.

Comment: The no areas will be all first calls to floodfill :)

Comment: I am using one call to FloodFill in main and then there are recursive calls. How to detect if there are first calls, Sorry if I sound too naive.

Comment: call Floodfill on point which is surely out of enclosed area. Then make calls on points which are yet unfilled using a scan over the plane. The total amount of calls excluding the very first one in which you filled the unenclosed area are  u r enclosed areas.

Comment: @Avinash: `void floodfill(...) { counter++; actualFloodFill(...); }`